# How to display only a certain part from Json data in React.js

Tags: reactjs, json

I wrote the code like below and show like photo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEoXN.png)

but

I want to show only "hour and minutes" like

**14:56**

Is it possible to display only hours and minutes like this?
If it is possible, how can I show it?

Json

```
    {     
        "time_start": "2022-12-22 14:56:00",
        "time_end": "2022-12-22 16:56:00",
    }
```

React.js

```
              {schedules.map(schedule => (
                <div className="each_scheduled" key={schedule.id}>
                  <div>
                  <p className="scheduled_p">Time</p>
                  <p className="scheduled_p">{schedule.time_start} - {schedule.time_end}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slice.

```
let time_start = "2022-12-22 14:56:00"
console.log(time_start.slice(11,-3))
//Output: 14:56
```

Comment: this works! thank you! <p className="scheduled_p">{schedule.time_start.slice(11,-3)} - {schedule.time_end.slice(11,-3)}</p>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the best approach, but you can split the date from the time like this:

```js
let time_start = "2022-12-22 14:56:00"

time_start = time_start.split(" ")

time_start[1] = time_start[1].substring(0, time_start[1].length-3);

console.log(time_start[1])
//Output: "14:56"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice you to work with a library dedicated for dates and times, it will make your life a lot easier, I highly suggest [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon)

with which your code could then look like so:

```js
// const { DateTime } = require('luxon')
// or with imports:
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'


// ... code ...

const times = schedules.map(schedule => {
  return {
    start: DateTime
          .fromFormat(schedule.time_start, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
          .toFormat('HH:mm'),
    end: DateTime
          .fromFormat(schedule.time_end, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
          .toFormat('HH:mm'),

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your time strings is fixed, you could use the [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function to slice the strings at appropriate indexes.

Changing your code as follows will achieve the desired result:

```
{schedules.map(schedule => (
                <div className="each_scheduled" key={schedule.id}>
                  <div>
                  <p className="scheduled_p">Time</p>
                  <p className="scheduled_p">{schedule.time_start.slice(11, 16)} - {schedule.time_end.slice(11, 16)}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
}
```